# convert mysql classes to mssql classes on php 5.3 version

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, pdo, sqlsrv

in my project, we used mysql. But now customer want to use mssql. i search, we use PDO or sqlsrv classes. But i can t decide which is suitable for our project or easily change this web application's structure?

my code example

```
class sql  {

public $oci;
public $rs;
public $temp;

public function __construct() {

    $this->oci = new mysqli(DBHOST, DBUSER, DBPASS,DBNAME);
    $this->oci->set_charset('utf8');

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {

           printf('Sql baglantı sorunu. Hata Kodu :' . mysqli_connect_errno());

           exit();
    }
}


public function closeOCI() {

    $this->oci->close();
}

public function query($query) {

    $this->rs = $this->oci->query($query);
}
```

and login class extends sql class

```
class login extends sql {


        public function loginControl($user, $pass)
        {

          $dbHandle = new sql($dbhost, $dbUserName, $dbPassWord, $dbCntDBName);
          //echo "SELECT level, name FROM users WHERE uName='$user' and pWord='$pass' limit 0,1";
          $dbHandle->query("SELECT level, name FROM users WHERE uName='$user' and pWord='$pass' limit 0,1");
          $result = $dbHandle->rs->fetch_assoc();

        return $result;
        }
```

}

which driver i can use or easily change them? 
thanx advide

Comment: I wouldn't have a class like your login class which simply depends on getting a class which can interact with the databse actually extend that DB class.  That really doesn't make sense.  You might instead consider injecting the DB object into the class at instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly what a database abstraction such as PDO is meant for.  If you need to support multiple DB platforms, you should consider using such an abstraction.

Alternately, you can build your own abstraction using which could for example use different classes based on mysql or mssql which implement a common interface or inherit from a common parent class.

Comment: no need multiple DB. only used Sqlserver 2012 or 2008

Comment: Then what is the question, how to port your code? How to make you code futureproof against such customer-driven backend changes in the future? Have you asked the customer whether they want you to simply port your code or to build an abstraction and given them the pros and cons of each?

Comment: exactly customer use another app which use Sqlserver and customer want my app and other use same DB. I ported data Sqlserver but not change code yet. Customer is politician government and in general what thay say, we have to accept. Is there any easy way to adapt?

Comment: @SerdarAlkan You are going to have to change your code either way, that is why I ask what you want to do, whether your customer has provided any input on whether they want you to abstract this out or simply port your code to MSSQL, or whether you have gone to them with a recommendation on your approach.  So really this is not a great question for SO, as it is really an opinion-based answer, and without having full context of your codebase, no one here is probably going to give an opinion which holds greater value than your own.

Comment: ok i see you. thanx advice. But customer have any idea technology and what else. In general not interesting how fix or provide or way. They interest that is completing or not completing. i have to port and i have to use one. thanx again